# value('.info/connected') and WIFI disconnect

Tags: firebase

We've come across an issue with the connection event.

With a Mac (at least), .info/connected does not trigger disconnected if you switch off the WIFI.

Is it a known issue? Is there something we're missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: On some browsers it may take a little while to notice the connection is offline (up-to a TCP timeout). No known issues, the client should eventually notice and trigger disconnect events. If it's not working as expected, please email support@firebase.com with details on the browser and OS versions.

Comment: Note that this could take up to 5 minutes in some extreme cases.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help! I'll try to find a more instantaneous way to detect the lost connection. I'll let you know if I find anything interesting.

Comment: @cwehrung have you found a faster way for this? i need an immediate disconnect fire for mission critical app using firebase as an intermediate staging area.